# Validation Rule Logic - AND vs OR

Tags: validation-rule

I have a validation rule that is intended to prevent users from creating a Contact without converting a Lead. It contains exceptions to allow certain users to do it. Logically, all of the conditions should be wrapped in an OR, but that doesn't work. It only works with an AND. I've been staring at this for over a month now, and I haven't figured it out. I have broken it down, tested them separately, and put it back together one condition at a time and it doesn't work with an OR. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. It looks like this:

```
AND(

  AND(
     ISNEW(),
     Converted_Lead_Contact__c = FALSE,
     AND(
        $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
        $Profile.Name <> "Advanced System Admin",
        $User.Username <> "user@company.com"
     )
  ),

  /* Exception for Partnerships */
  AND(
     ISNEW(),
     Converted_Lead_Contact__c = FALSE,
     Account.RecordType.Name = "Partnership",
     $Profile.Name <> "Partnerships",
     OR(
       ISPICKVAL(Account.Partnership_Status__c, "Executing Agreement"),
       ISPICKVAL(Account.Partnership_Status__c, "Active Partner"),
       ISPICKVAL(Account.Partnership_Status__c, "Former Partner")
     )
  ),

  /* Exception for Sales */
  AND(
     ISNEW(),
     Converted_Lead_Contact__c = FALSE,
     OR(
       ISPICKVAL(Account.Account_Status__c, "Working Renewal"),
       ISPICKVAL(Account.Account_Status__c, "Active Client"),
       ISPICKVAL(Account.Account_Status__c, "Open Opp")
     ),
     AND(
        $Profile.Name <> "Account Director",
        $Profile.Name <> " Managing Director"
     )
  )

)
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! If you haven't yet, please take a moment to read about [ask] and take the [tour]. This is a very decently made first question, although you could [edit] it to improve the question to include examples of times the rule should fire but does not. This would help improve the quality of the question even further. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is actually a NOR operation (NOT-OR). Unlike AND, this will only return true when none of the conditions are met. I also shuffled around the operations to make them more performant and legible.

However, this changed some of the operations, so let's go over it in pieces.

```
AND(
    ISNEW(),
    NOT(Converted_Lead_Contact__c),
    ...
)
```

These are the common checks.

```
NOT(
    OR(
        ...
    )
)
```

This sets up our NOR operation. It returns true only when all of the inner conditions are NOT met.

## Rule 1

```
OR(
    1 = CASE(
        $Profile.Name
        "System Administrator", 1,
        "Advanced System Admin", 1, 
        0
    ),
    $User.Username = "user@company.com"
)
```

If they are one of two profiles, or a specific user, return true (this will be inverted to false at the end). Note we had to change `<>` to `=`. This will be a theme.

Also note the use of `1 = CASE(...)` as a matter of efficiently comparing one field to multiple values. This will also be a theme.

## Rule 2

```
/* Exception for Partnerships */
AND(
    Account.RecordType.Name = "Partnership",
    $Profile.Name = "Partnerships",
    1 = CASE(
        Account.Partnership_Status__c, 
        "Executing Agreement", 1,
        "Active Partner", 1,
        "Former Partner", 1,
        0
    )
),
```

Similarly, if it is a Partnership record type, the profile matches, and the status is one of those status values, this returns true (again, will make the rule false).

## Rule 3

```
/* Exception for Sales */
AND(
    1 = CASE(
        Account.Account_Status__c, 
        "Working Renewal", 1,
        "Active Client", 1,
        "Open Opp", 1,
        0
    ),
    1 = CASE(
        $Profile.Name,
        "Account Director", 1,
        "Managing Director", 1,
        0
    )
)
```

Finally, if the user is one of two profiles, and the account has one of those status values, return true so the rule can pass.

## Summary

Now, if any one of these three scenarios pass, the entire rule will pass. Otherwise, if the two initial conditions are false, and none of these three exceptions apply, we trigger the validation error.

## A Note

There's no reason why this needs to be one rule. You can use three separate rules, and provide three distinct error messages. This is arguably more user friendly, and may be easier to maintain in the long run. After all, you had to learn an entirely new concept, the NOR operation, just to make this work. Those who follow you might be similarly confused (note: please do feel free to leave a link to this answer for them to read).

## Final Code

```
AND(
    ISNEW(),
    NOT(Converted_Lead_Contact__c),
    NOT(
        OR(
            /* Rule #1: Allow admins to edit */
            OR(
                1 = CASE(
                    $Profile.Name
                    "System Administrator", 1,
                    "Advanced System Admin", 1, 
                    0
                ),
                $User.Username <> "user@company.com"
            ),
            /* Rule #2: Allow Partnerships profile to partner accounts */
            AND(
                Account.RecordType.Name = "Partnership",
                $Profile.Name = "Partnerships",
                1 = CASE(
                    Account.Partnership_Status__c, 
                    "Executing Agreement", 1,
                    "Active Partner", 1,
                    "Former Partner", 1,
                    0
                )
            ),
            /* Rule #3: Allow Sales to create contacts on accounts they're working */
            AND(
                1 = CASE(
                    Account.Account_Status__c, 
                    "Working Renewal", 1,
                    "Active Client", 1,
                    "Open Opp", 1,
                    0
                ),
                1 = CASE(
                    $Profile.Name,
                    "Account Director", 1,
                    "Managing Director", 1,
                    0
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: this was brilliant. I couldn't be satisfied knowing it worked without knowing why. In the end, you're right, I could've broken this down into 3 rules. That's exactly what I'm going to do, but thanks for adding another arrow to my quiver.

Answer (score 3):

Validation rules continue to mess with my mind to this day.

The thing that keeps tripping me up is that if a validation rule evaluates to `true`, then the validation rule prevents the dml from completing. It feels like the opposite of what I've been conditioned (through education and experience) to think.

If we want to except certain situations from triggering the validation rule, we need to use `AND` (as you've found out) in cases where the exemption conditions are mutually exclusive (a person cannot have both {profile A} and {profile B}). It's only in the case where a person meets *none* of the exemption criteria that we want the validation rule to fire.

AND is the logical "all or nothing" operator, so it makes sense to use it for exemptions. It might help to think of the outermost operator as a NAND or NOR.

Since `ISNEW(), Converted_Lead_Contact__c = FALSE` is common to all your subconditions, it should be possible to factor those out and simplify your validation rule a bit.

```
AND(
    ISNEW(),
    Converted_Lead_Contact__c = FALSE,
    AND(
        $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
        $Profile.Name <> "Advanced System Admin",
        $User.Username <> "user@company.com"
    ),
    /* Exception for Partnerships */
    AND(
        OR(
           ISPICKVAL(Account.Partnership_Status__c, "Executing Agreement"),
           ISPICKVAL(Account.Partnership_Status__c, "Active Partner"),
           ISPICKVAL(Account.Partnership_Status__c, "Former Partner")
        ),
        Account.RecordType.Name = "Partnership",
        $Profile.Name <> "Partnerships",
    ),
    /* Exception for Sales */
    AND(
        OR(
            ISPICKVAL(Account.Account_Status__c, "Working Renewal"),
            ISPICKVAL(Account.Account_Status__c, "Active Client"),
            ISPICKVAL(Account.Account_Status__c, "Open Opp")
        ),
        AND(
            $Profile.Name <> "Account Director",
            $Profile.Name <> " Managing Director"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Goodness, I spent all that time typing just to not notice you were here like ten minutes before me. Though, to be fair, I did include some extras you missed.

Comment: Oh, actually, it looks like you fell into the same "trap" OP did. You'll want to read your answer again really carefully and compare it to mine. I think you'll find your mistake. I had to triple-check my own work before I even posted.

Comment: My apologies for the spams, but I thought I'd provide an example, consider a Partnership Status of, say, "Not a Partner" and a profile of "Partnerships". This would violate the intention of the second exception, but would not trigger the rule.

Comment: @sfdcfox This is why I dread adding exemptions to validation rules. I think I'll need to come back to this one tomorrow.

Comment: @DerekF this here: "The thing that keeps tripping me up is that if a validation rule evaluates to true, then the validation rule prevents the dml from completing. It feels like the opposite of what I've been conditioned (through education and experience) to think." I feel like I have to rewire my brain every time I do a complex validation. So with the exception of pulling out the common elements (which I wanted to do, but my eyes were already going cross and I wanted to be as explicit as possible), looks like my rule is correct. It's just my conceptual understanding of why that's lacking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to work out the specifics of what you're trying to do since sfdcfox already did that. I wanted to cover it in general terms.

There are two important things to consider when writing a validation rule:

1. The rule's expression specifies the **failure conditions**
2. Boolean logic has some interesting and only-obvious-when-you-really-think-about-it behaviours

When writing your validation rule, you might think about the success case, not the failure case, yet you **must** write the logic to return TRUE (normally considered a "success") **when it fails**. Let me repeat that, you must write an expression that is TRUE for a failure only.

If you wish to allow exceptions to this failure, **any one of these exceptions** must ensure the end result is FALSE.

Now consider some simple logic points:

- "A and B" is only ever TRUE when A is TRUE and B is TRUE
- "A or B" is only ever FALSE when A is FALSE and B is FALSE

Note the way I expressed these and you will see the logic structure is the same but using the opposite Boolean values. This is, in fact, an expression of [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

If you have a condition A that expresses **failure** (so is TRUE for a failure), and condition B that is an **exception to that failure** (so is TRUE when the exception applies and failure should be avoided), you want to ensure that the overall expression only returns TRUE if A is TRUE and B is FALSE. I.e. you need an expression of the form `A AND NOT B`.

On the other hand if your mindset was "what constitutes the success case", your condition A expresses **success** (so is TRUE when being allowed), and your exception expression B is (still) TRUE when the exception applies (when failure is to be avoided), you want to ensure that the overall expression only returns TRUE if A is FALSE and B is FALSE. I.e. you need an validation rule expression of the form `NOT A AND NOT B`. Using De Morgan's Law, you can re-express this as `NOT (A OR B)` if you so wish.

When you have multiple exception cases, simply consider these as contributing to B (your exceptions) in the above explanation; in this case you want *any one of the exceptions* to lead to B being TRUE, so you need to OR these values together - B is TRUE if any one of the exceptions applies. You can think of this as `A AND NOT (B1 OR B2 OR ...)` in the validation rule (when A expresses the required failure by returning TRUE).

When writing your logic you may express it sub-optimally (you may have aspects you could pull out to be common) but I would suggest you only simplify the expression if it won't add confusion when re-visiting the validation expression later.